# What's the difference between Miss Fortune and Mysterious Stranger?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

[The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_perks) describes both perks in shorthand with the following text:

> Chance that `name` will finish off a target in VATS.

Where `name` is either Miss Fortune or Mysterious Stranger. However, the official perk text for them is slightly different. For [Miss Fortune](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Miss_Fortunate):

> Just when your enemies think they have
>   the upper hand, Miss Fortune appears
>   to turn their world upside down.
>   Appearing only in V.A.T.S., she has
>   the ability to snatch defeat from the
>   jaws of victory.

For [Mysterious Stranger](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Stranger):

> You've gained your own personal
>   guardian angel... armed with a fully
>   loaded .44 Magnum. With this perk, the
>   Mysterious Stranger will appear
>   occasionally in V.A.T.S. mode to lend
>   a hand, with deadly efficiency.

Is there any functional difference other than gender, or is that it?

Comment: Hm. I would have thought it was Miss Fortune, but Fortunate appears to be correct. Hunh.

Comment: I know. I typed up the whole question as "Miss Fortune," then went back and checked and edited it before posting. :)

Comment: So it appears that Miss Fortune is, in fact, the correct spelling after all.

Comment: Yep, based on in-game. Wikia had it misspelled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Miss Fortune appears randomly when attacking in V.A.T.S, and has a roughly one in three chance to use each of her attacks, they are:

1. A Knockdown against your current target
2. Disarm your target -  the weapon will be flung across the room. If your opponent is unarmed, this result will never occur.
3. Cripple a random limb. There is a higher than average chance of this being the torso, and a slightly lower than average chance of this being the head.

By contrast, the Mysterious Stranger will only appear if, at the end of a V.A.T.S. attack, a foe has less than 150 HP to finish them off with a headshot from his .44 Magnum.

The chance of an appearance for either is 10%, though this can be doubled with the Friendly Help perk, acquired when you receive 15 visits from either the Stranger or Miss Fortune.